# Laravel 4 update slug

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have it so that when a new branch is created the name gets turned into a slug for lookup, but when I update the record the slug variable stays the same, is there a way to have it automatically update whenever the record is changed?

```
class Branch extends \Eloquent {

    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required'
    ];

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];

    protected function setNameAttribute($name)
    {
        $this->attributes['name'] = $name;
        $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($name);
    }
}
```

and in my controller...

```
public function update($slug)
{
    $branch = Branch::whereSlug($slug);

    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::except('_method', '_token'), Branch::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $branch->update($data);

    return Redirect::route('branches.index');
}
```

Comment: I've just updated my answer with something else I noticed - just mentioning in case you've already read it and wouldn't notice the edit :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the model event should kick in to the mutator **if it's the Eloquent model you're dealing with** - the Fluent query builder won't. I **think** that `Branch::whereSlug($slug)` returns a Fluent query builder - just check to see if `Branch::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail()` works. I think it probably will.

---

Failing that, there are two options that I'd recommend - first off, Colin Viebrock has an excellent [package for generating slugs](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) which is super easy to use.

If you'd rather homebrew it, I'd just put it in the `boot` method using a [model event](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events):

```
public static function boot() {
    static::saving( function( $model ) {
        $model->name = $model->name; // force the slug to be rebuilt
    } );
}
```

Comment: Yea, I'd think adding the ->firstOrFail() would fix it ;)  I also thought the attribute setter would be called on update too, this could seem like the problem ;)

Comment: hi there, thanks... your right, I just forgot the ->firstOrFail() !! +1 for the slug package, and the boot() method, i'll look into it :D cheers!